# How to use Splash with python-requests?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, python-requests, splash-screen, scrapyjs

I want to use splash in [**requests**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), something like this

```
requests.post(myUrl,headers=myHeaders, data=payload, meta={
                                        'splash': {
                                            'endpoint': 'render.html',
                                            'args': {'wait': 1}
                                            }
                                        })
```

but I have this error

```
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'meta'
```

I know that this work with **scrapy.Request** but I want to use with [**requests**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`meta` is Scrapy `Request`-specific and [python-requests' request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request) does not have a `meta` argument, hence the `TypeError` exception.

To use Splash with python-requests, read the [HTTP API docs, especially on `render.html`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#render-html) as this is what you want to use it seems.

You'll want a GET request to the `/render.html` endpoint, and pass target URL, and `wait` argument as query parameter, e.g. like this:

```
import requests
requests.get('http://localhost:8050/render.html',
             params={'url': 'http://www.example.com', 'wait': 2})
```

If you want Splash to issue a POST request to the target website, use `http_method` and `body` arguments:

```
import requests
requests.get('http://localhost:8050/render.html',
              params={'url': 'http://httpbin.org/post',
                      'http_method': 'POST',
                      'body': 'a=b',
                      'wait': 2})
```

`/render.html` also [allows POST-ed requests to the endpoint](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#splash-http-api):

> Splash is controlled via HTTP API. For all endpoints below parameters may be sent either as GET arguments or encoded to JSON and POSTed with `Content-Type: application/json` header.

but the default method is still GET. To do a POST to the target website, you still need to include a `http_method` argument:

```
import requests

requests.post('http://localhost:8050/render.html',
              json={'url': 'http://httpbin.org/post',
                    'http_method': 'POST',
                    'body': 'a=b',
                    'wait': 2})
```

Comment: But i should send a POST request

Comment: Do you mean that Splash should issue a POST request to the target website? If yes, there are [`http_method` and `body` arguments](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#render-html) available with `/render.html`